# getting a matplotlib colorbar tick outside data limits for use with boundaries keyword

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to use a colorbar to label discrete, coded values plotted using imshow. I can achieve the colorbar that I want using the `boundaries` and `values` keywords, which makes the maximum value of the colorbar effectively 1 greater than the maximum value of the data being plotted.

Now I want ticks to be in the middle of each color range in the colorbar, but cannot specify a tick position for the largest color block in the colorbar, seemingly because it is outside of the data value limits.

Here's a quick block of code to demonstrate the problem:

```
data = np.tile(np.arange(4), 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.imshow(data[None], aspect='auto')
cax = fig.add_subplot(122)
cbar = fig.colorbar(ax.images[0], cax=cax, boundaries=[0,1,2,3,4], values=[0,1,2,3])
cbar.set_ticks([.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5])
cbar.set_ticklabels(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
```

Note the missing tick where 'four' should be. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I have since hacked a solution by not using Figure.colorbar, instead plotting `range(max(data) + 1)` in the cax axes, and then setting the axis ticks and labels as required. It would, however, be nice if there was a clean way to do this using colorbar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To summarize, this works for me:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import colors

data = np.tile(np.arange(4), 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 4)
bounds = np.arange(5)
vals = bounds[:-1]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
ax.imshow(data[None], aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

cax = fig.add_subplot(122)
cbar = fig.colorbar(ax.images[0], cax=cax, boundaries=bounds, values=vals)
cbar.set_ticks(vals + .5)
cbar.set_ticklabels(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
```

The solution was to specify the colormap explicitly for the image using `get_cmap` and bounded by `BoundaryNorm`. Then specifying the tick positions just works. The resulting plot is:

[image: discrete colorbar example]

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the same `colormap` in `imshow` and `cbar`. As your `data` and `cbar` is defined in the same way (same limits etc.) so you do not realize the inconsistency in the above example. You should define the `colormap` first.

Let's say you want to divide your data into 4-discrete colors, then you can use

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib import colors, cm

data = np.tile(np.arange(4), 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
cax = fig.add_subplot(122)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 4) # 4 discrete color
im=ax.imshow(data[None], aspect='auto',cmap=cmap)
cbar = fig.colorbar(ax.images[0], cax=cax, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can now put the `ticks` according to your need.

In case you want to define the bounds as well as the colors in these bounds then you can use `ListedColormap` as follows:

```
data = np.tile(np.arange(4), 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
cax = fig.add_subplot(122)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['b','g','y','r'])
bounds=[0,1,2,3,4]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
im=ax.imshow(data[None], aspect='auto',cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds, ticks=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5],)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is not quite correct: by default the colorbar does take the colormap of the mappable (in this case the image in `ax`; look in matplotlib's colorbar.py:Colobar.__init__), so specifying the colormap in the call to colorbar is not necessary.  
Specifying the truncated cmap using `get_cmap`, and applying the `BoundaryNorm` normalization did fix the problem. Thanks for those pointers.

Comment: Of course the default `colormap` is `jet`. What I meant by defining the `colormap` was to put the `bounds` so that limits in both plots are same - essentially what you are doing now.