# Setting the limits on a colorbar of a contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have seen so many examples that just don't apply to my case. What I would like to do is set a simple minimum and maximum value for a colorbar. Setting a range for an image cmap is easy but this does not apply the same range to the minimum and maximum values of the colorbar.
The code below may explain:

```
triang = Triangulation(x,y)
plt.tricontourf(triang, z, vmax=1., vmin=0.)
plt.colorbar()
```

The colorbar is still fixed to the limits of the data z, although the cmap range is now fixed between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[I propose you incorporate you plot in a fig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570627/getting-a-matplotlib-colorbar-tick-outside-data-limits-for-use-with-boundaries-k) and get inspiration from this sample using the colorbar

```
data = np.tile(np.arange(4), 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
cax = fig.add_subplot(122)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['b','g','y','r'])
bounds=[0,1,2,3,4]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
im=ax.imshow(data[None], aspect='auto',cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds, 
     ticks=[0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5],)
plt.show()
```

you see that you can set `bounds` for the colors in colorbar and ticks.

it is not rigourously what you want to achieve, but the hint to fig could help.

[This other one uses `ticks`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826592/python-matplotlib-colorbar-range-and-display-values) as well to define the scale of colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xi = np.array([0., 0.5, 1.0])
yi = np.array([0., 0.5, 1.0])
zi = np.array([[0., 1.0, 2.0],
               [0., 1.0, 2.0],
               [-0.1, 1.0, 2.0]])

v = np.linspace(-.1, 2.0, 15, endpoint=True)
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, v, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, v, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
x = plt.colorbar(ticks=v)
print x
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great! This works. I tried this earlier but missed the v inside plt.contourf. That's why it wasn't working. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

I thought this question pointed out a bug, but it turns it's a usage/compatability constraint. The solution is to create the contours for the range of the colorbar that you want, and use the `extend` kwarg.  For more information, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5055). Thanks to [@tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell) for providing this solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.mgrid[0:1:0.01, 0:1:0.01]
r = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
z = np.sin(6 * np.pi * r)

fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots(1, 1, )
cf0 = ax0.contourf(x, y, z, np.arange(0, .5, .01),
                   extend='both')
cbar0 = plt.colorbar(cf0,)
```

[image]

From here if you don't like the colorbar ticks, you can adjust them with `cbar0.set_ticks`. I've verified that this also works with `tricontourf`.

I've simplified @tcaswell's code to that which is needed to get the desired result. Also, he used the new viridis colormap, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: The pointy-tips on the colorbar indicate that the data continues but the contour coloring stops. You can control the presence of these tips with the `extend` kwarg, but know that if you don't use it you won't have any coloring (contours) outside the range you specify.

Answer (score 10):

This is the simplest method probably.

...(your code as shown)

```
plt.colorbar(boundaries=np.linspace(0,1,5))
```

...

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem, and came up with a concrete (albeit meaningless) example of this problem. The commented contourf command will create a color bar that has the same bounds as the data, and not the color limits.

The level option of tricontourf seems to be a good way to work around this, though it requires the extend='both' option to include values that exceed the levels in the plot.

```
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
from matplotlib import colors

numpy.random.seed(0)
x = randn(300)
y = randn(300)
z = randn(*x.shape)
triangles = mtri.Triangulation(x, y)
bounds=np.linspace(-1,1,10)
# sc = plt.tricontourf(triangles, z, vmax=1., vmin=-1.)
sc = plt.tricontourf(triangles, z, vmax=1., vmin=-1., levels = bounds,\
                    extend = 'both')
cb = colorbar(sc)
_ = ylim(-2,2)
_ = xlim(-2,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own take, which I personally find to be a bit more clear and unified

```
density=10
x = np.linspace(-1,1,num=density,endpoint=True)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,num=density,endpoint=True)
x = x.repeat(density)
y = np.hstack((y,)*density)
z = np.e**(-(x**2+y**2))

fig,  ax = plt.subplots()


vmin=0.30
vmax=0.60
plot_val = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 300, endpoint=True)


cntr = ax.tricontourf(x, y, z, plot_val,
                      vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax,
                      extend='both'
                 )

cbar = fig.colorbar(cntr,ax=ax)
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(0,0.61,0.1))
```